# Check if user input strings contain the same letters

Tags: java, compare

How can I check if strings put in by the user via scanner (the user can choose how many words he wants to type in) contain the same letters? Lets say the users types in the following 3 words:

race
bicycle
computer

Every word in this example contains 'e' and 'c'. How can I compare those strings and safe the result (e and c) in a new string?

```
public class Comparison {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String letters = "";


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many words do you want to type in?:");
    count = input.nextInt();

    String[] words= new String[count];


    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].charAt(0) == words[j].charAt(0)) {
            letters = letters + words[i].charAt(j);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried methods like indexOf and charAt but they've only worked for a fixed string count for me like if I have two strings then it worked but with input from a user its a different story

Comment: Please **show us** what you have tried ...

Comment: so if you can do this for 2 words, you can do it for n words. If there are 2 words, great. If not, do it for the first two words, and make the result your new first word. Repeat until there are just two words, do once more, and you're done. You can get the words with split. And if you get that working, you could then have it quit early if the overlap is empty. Also, you set up the place to put the words, but you did not read them.

Comment: also, it might be worth clarifying what the answer should be for bocce soccer raccoon: co or cco

Answer (score 0):

There are several pieces needed here.

1. Get the words from the user with a scanner. You are not asking about that. The idea would be to prompt, read in the input, and generate an array of strings. One way to do that might be to use the split method. You were not asking about this part. You asked what to do with this string array once you had it. To test the other parts you could use args passed to main, then develop this piece.
2. A method to find the common letters between just two strings. You indicated that you had such a method working. So I am not going to share that. Let's just imagine it looked like:

   /**

   - Method findCommonLetters
     *
   - @param word1 first word
   - @param word2 second word
   - @return a string containing the common letters in the two words, no repeats
     */

   public String findCommonLetters(String word1, String word2) {
   //your code here
    }
3. A way to take an arbitrary length array of strings and get the letters all have in common. That is what you were asking for. Here is a method that will do that assuming you have the method described in 2 working. The idea is to work through just 2 at a time and look for only those letters in common in all the words so far in the next word (and loop until we have processed all the words). Code follows:

   /**

   - Method findCommonLetters
     *
   - @param words An array of words
   - @return A String containing the letters to all the words
     */

public String findCommonLetters(String[] words)

```
 {
            if (words.length == 0) {
                return ""; //there are no letters
            } else if (words.length == 1) {
                //if the desired behavior is as I do here, this else if block could go away
                return words[0]; //trivially all the words have the same letters
            } else {
                String result = words[0]; // first word
                for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
                    result = findCommonLetters(result, words[i]); //find letters in common between all words processed so far and next word
                    //if you want, you could break here if result is empty
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Putting together these three pieces will give the desired result.